# Make a for loop repeat forever

Tags: code-golf, python

`for` loops are useful in python in many ways, but one of the most common usages associated with a `for` loop is it's ability to repeat a certain amount of times. Like this:

```
for times in range(50):
    print "I'm repeating this 50 times..."
```

The challenge I propose to you is to make a `for` repeat **forever**. If you can find a way to do it without using a recursion, kudos to you. You can use **any** major version of Python. Just specify which one you are using. The goal is to do this in the smallest file size you can get, and a method that won't "break" after a while. Good luck!

Comment: Ewwww, language-specific challenges. (See http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/234/3 for my stance on this.) (This is unrelated to the reason why I closed the question, which is a site rule and not just a personal opinion.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I personally think it's fair for programming-puzzles, as they usually tend to work around some feature of a specific language. You could have told the OP though, that your closing the question has nothing to do with your not liking language-specific challenges. So, @ Some Guy, the question is closed because you did not indicate who (among several correct solutions) you will pick the winner of the challenge. Votes? Code-length? Something else?

Comment: @m.buettner There, I edited my comment to say that now. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Befunge will surely win if this is non-language-specific code-golf.

Comment: @user23013 Of course. It was the winning entry in my [stack overflow code golf](http://stackoverflow.com/q/62188/13). ;-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I have added basic criteria to help decided a winner. This probably isn't enough to re-open the question though... Sorry to the users who answered this question before I added goals in order to choose a winner.

Comment: @SomeGuy Thank you. I have retagged the question as a code golf since the winning criterion is shortest code.

Comment: Here's an idea to make this non-language-specific: "implement a foreach loop that repeats forever"

Comment: @TheRare Changing the accepted answer is absolutely legitimate if a new winner comes along (by the specified criteria). Therefore, the currently accepted answer isn't even the correct one, actually.

Comment: @m.buettner Well then, I take your word on that.

Comment: Wait... is this [tag:code-golf] or [tag:popularity-contest]? I'm confused.

Comment: @Iszi Pop contest.

Comment: The question and one tag state that it's code-golf. The previous comment and another tag state that it's pop-con. It can't be both.

Comment: It's code golf, but it would have been far better as an underhanded popularity contest.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Eww, [here's](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32782/survival-game-alienwar) another language-specific challenge. Doesn't look like it's getting hate for that.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms King-of-the-Hill contests are a special exception, to make concessions for OPs who want to test out the entries and not have to install many language runtimes in order to do so. However, there are still ways to run language-independent KotH contests (e.g., using virtual machines), and I still encourage people to do it.

Comment: `perl6 -e 'for 0..* {print "$_\r"}'` only 11 required characters, or `perl6 -e 'print "$_\r" for 0..*'` only 10 chars required ( there has to be something before `for` separated by whitespace `0 for 0..*`)

Comment: I didn't know you had time for code-golfing, M. Putin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this was turned to a codegolf, have a **48 bytes** version as a one-liner. 3 bytes could be removed from both by replacing `print i` with `pass`.

```python
for i in __import__('itertools').count():print i
```

Or a **47 bytes** version with two lines.

```python
from itertools import*
for i in count():print i
```

---

Old message:

Easy it is.

```python
def f(i = 0):
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1
for i in f():
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 11):

This can be done quite easily by abusing floating point addition.

```
def frange(start, stop, step):
    r = start
    while r < stop:
        yield r
        r += step

for x in frange(0, 1e16, 1):
    print (x)
```

IEEE754 64-bit floats have 53 bits of mantissa (including the implicit bit), so if `x > 1<<53` then `x + 1 == x`. `1 << 53` is approximately `9e15`.

Comment: Are you sure this won't transform to a long?

Comment: @TheRare, why would it transform to a long? That aside, [a simple test](http://ideone.com/ufEJdO) shows arithmetic behaving as expected.

Comment: That is actually pretty interesting.

Answer (score 6):

This is an interesting way of doing it (32 chars for `class x`, 46 not counting the `print`):

```python
class x:__iter__=next=lambda s:s
for i in x():print "Hello"
```

This defines an iterable whose `next` method never raises a `StopIteration`

Comment: Actually, the `next` method is the `__iter__` method (which is supposed to return the iterable). Both return `self` (`s`)

Answer (score 3):

I don't usually golf in Python, probably some reason people haven't already done posted this 23-character solution.

```
x=[1]
for i in x:
 x+=x
```

Much less memory-hungry if you do `x+=[i]` instead. Either one hangs my 2.7.5

Comment: "and a method that won't "break" after a while." So that's why no one has done this. Or maybe it's because no one was smart enough to think of it.

Comment: Well, this does explode the memory very quickly, because the memory usage raises exponentially.

Comment: Yeah, the `+=[i]` version seems almost legitimate though, I don't know if that would break within any reasonable amount of time. Either way, not as interesting a solution as the others.

Comment: It would probably break **eventually**, when the list reaches `sys.maxsize` items.

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in iter(lambda : 0, 1): 
    print (i) # prints 0 forever
```

The `iter` function is normally used to create an iterator from an iterable.

The `iter` function can also take two arguments, a callable and a sentinel value. In that case it returns an iterator that yields the result of the callable until the callable returns the sentinel value.

In this case, the callable is a lambda that always returns 0. Since it never can return the sentinel value (1), this will loop forever.

Since this is code golf, this version is **28 characters and only one line**:

```
for i in iter(lambda:0,1):i
```

Answer (score 2):

## 28 bytes, infinite, and no itertools

```
for x in iter(int,1):print 1
```

Shouldn't end without system program cutoffs (i.e. not my fault).

#### 22 bytes without printing anything:

```
for x in iter(int,1):1
```

Answer (score 1):

Itertools, to the rescue:

```
from itertools import count
for i in count():
    print i
```

or

```
from itertools import repeat
for i in repeat(42):
    print i
```

Comment: Just an fyi, `itertools.count` is the same as my answer and `itertools.repeat` is almost the same as my original answer.

Comment: @TheRare I suppose, but I'd rather use `itertools.count` in an production environment than something home-brew.

Comment: Absolutely. Just wanted to inform that the implementation is the same.

Answer (score 1):

### 39 Characters, no itertools and no crashing

```
def f():
 while 1:yield
for i in f():1
```

Itertools is unnecessary, you can define your own generator.

Comment: You don't need to use `pass` - `1` or `i` will do just as well.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 & 3: 37 characters

```
class P:__getitem__=id
for t in P():1
```

¡No infinite memory required!

Answer (score 0):

#### Python 3.3: 2 lines, 29 characters

```
j=[1]  
for i in j: j.append(1)
```

Does this break? I've run it for a short while, doesn't seem to hang.

Comment: This will run out of memory, just like histocrat's version.

Comment: @m.buettner indeed it will. Hmm.